# Selenium 3.3.1 wait.unit is throwing an error java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, V>)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have upgraded my selenium webdriver to 3.2.0 from 3.0.1 and observed that

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("myID"));
```

if displaying compilation error as below:

The method

```
until((java.util.function.Function<? super 
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, V>) 
 ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("myID")));
```

When I move back to selenium 3.0.1 it is working as expected.

Is there a problem with 3.2.0 or 3.3.1, how to fix this issue

Answer (score 6):

Update your guava package to version 21

Answer (score 2):

FluentWait method until() is Deprecated in lattest selenium support 3.2.0 and up. If you really needed use the latest version of selenium and want to use selenium-support fluent wait, then can use selenium-support 3.0.1. Selenium 3.2.0 contains selenium support 3.2.0 which does not support until(). If you are using can just add the following dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: At last I could use below code to fix the issue

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 30);
    Function<WebDriver, Boolean> myFunction = new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
 public Boolean apply(WebDriver arg0) 
 {
  System.out.println("Checking for the object!!");
  WebElement element = arg0.findElement(By.id("dynamicText"));
  if (element != null) 
  {
   System.out.println("A new dynamic object is found.");
  }
  return true; 
 }
 };

 wait.until(myFunction);